# Pass additional parameters to functions within lodash's flow()

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

If I want to change the delimiter of join() to something other than the default, how do I pass that to that specific function within this chain?

```
const evens = (x) => _.filter(x, y => y % 2 === 0)

console.log(
  _.flow(
    evens,
    _.join,
  )([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
) 
// expected output: ('2+4+6')
// actual output: ('2,4,6')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```js
const evens = (x) => _.filter(x, y => y % 2 === 0)

console.log(
  _.flow(
    evens,
    (a) => _.join(a, '+'),
  )([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```